# Regular expression: Match only if not followed by a duplicate character

Tags: regex

I'm highlighting all words between pipes `|` using `/\|(.+?)\|/g`, for example, `|mathSign|`; the `mathSign` will be hilighted.

However, it has some cases that we write double pipes `||` for another meaning as following:

```
 function |mathSign| (x) {
     return |((x === 0 || isNaN(x)) ? x : (x > 0 ? 1 : -1))|; 
 }
```

The pattern matches `|((x === 0 |` and `| isNaN(x)) ? x : (x > 0 ? 1 : -1))|` which is wrong. The right one should ignore the `||` in the middle.

I tried to use `lookahead` concept; `/\|(.+?)\|(?!\|)/g` in order to ignore if the pipe followed by another pipe, however, still no luck. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Please see my [Demo](http://regexr.com/3bg7k) in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
\|((?:\|\||[^|])+)\|
```

- `\|\|` - Match greedily when `||` appears.
- `|` - OR
- `[^|]` - Match any char but not of `|`
- `+` - One or more times.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3bg7n)

```js
var s = "function |mathSign| (x) {\n     return |((x === 0 || isNaN(x)) ? x : (x > 0 ? 1 : -1))|; \n }";
alert(s.match(/\|((?:\|\||[^|])+)\|/g))
```